# Prove that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1} x^n/n$ is not uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{x^n}{n}$ is not uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$ using the Uniform Cauchy Criterion.

The negation of Uniform Cauchy Criterion is the following: $$\exists \epsilon\, \forall N \,\exists x\in(-1,1)\,\exists n,m>N:\displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{k=m}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k}\right\vert\geqslant\epsilon.$$ 
I derived that
$$\sum_{k=m}^n \frac{x^k}{k}\leqslant \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=m}^n x^k=\frac{1}{m}\frac{x^{m+1}-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$
How should I proceed? I always find it difficult to prove these things, since I need to pick an $\epsilon$ and pick an $x$ et cetera..

Comment: I think there's a typo in your last expression.  Shouldn't $x^{m+1}$ be $x^m?$  Be that as it may, the question you need to think about is, "How can the last expression be made large?"  What is the limit as $x\to 1-$ for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that it were, then for some $N$, for all $x\in(-1,1)$ and $m\geq N$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dfrac{x^{k}}{k}\right|<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
taking $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\leq\epsilon,~~~~m\geq N,
\end{align*}
this shows that $\left\{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy and hence convergent, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

First, your last term in the UCC should be $\left\vert \sum_{k=m}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k}\right\vert\geqslant\epsilon$.

**Hint 1:** Try picking $n=2m$. You can do this because you need to find $m,n,x$.

Your problem boils to 
$$\left\vert \sum_{k=m}^{2m} \dfrac{x^k}{k}\right\vert\geqslant\epsilon$$

**Hint 2** Note that 
$$\left\vert \sum_{k=m}^{2m} \dfrac{x^k}{k}\right\vert\geqslant \left\vert \sum_{k=m}^{2m} \dfrac{x^{2m}}{2m}\right\vert=\frac{x^{2m}}{2}$$

If you can make this greater than $\epsilon$ you are done.

**Hint 3** Use that for a fixed $N$, if you pick any $m>N$, for this **fixed** $m$ you have
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{2m}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

All you need to do is pick the right $\epsilon$, then for all $N$ fix some $m>N$, pick $n=2m$ and find the right $x$.